# Query to get count of rows with and without a value - 1query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count how many rows has given value (1) and count how many row has value(0)

```
id XXX 1 <==  value 0 or 1
id YYY 1
id ZZZ 0
```

so the result would be

```
ones | zeros
2    | 0
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) ones
, sum(case when value = 0 then 1 else 0 end) zeros
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select sum(if(value=0,1,0)) as zeros,
       sum(if(value=1,1,0)) as ones
from mytable
```